# Rails Active_Admin VS. my own backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, admin, backend, activeadmin

I've been thinking of writing my own backend, because I feel active_admin might not support all the requirements. 
I wanted to ask if Active_Admin supports any of these just to be sure:

1. I have a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship between my ad model
   and tag model. In the new ad page I would like to have the form for
   the ads, as well as all available tags so the admin can choose which
   tags to associate with the ad. I was able to do that normally in my
   application, but can I do that with active_admin?
2. Can I add custom buttons.. Like one to convert to PDF for example,
   or one to send an e-mail..
3. Could I add some sort of before_filter, so the admin can only view a
   model, but not edit or delete it for example?

Thank you.

Comment: Active_admin can be a nightmare if you want too much personalisation. I think it's better to avoid using it if you want something really like you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried an implemented almost all robust gems for admin panels. I have also sweated over several hand-made ones.

Active-Admin is very usability centred, but it is not configuration centred.

As you rightly aniticipated, some of the more complex modifications can be tedious.

In my experience, [rails_admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) is the best middle ground I could find.

Take a look at it, it is highly functional, completely modular (made as a Rails 3 Engine) and simpler to modify.

If you can live without some details when customizing this is definitely the way to go. However, if you need to have everything just right, then there is not substitute for hand-made.

Comment: @ninja08 Check out this 3 part article - http://everydayrails.com/2012/07/31/rails-admin-panel-from-scratch.html or this one as a primer - http://www.iain.nl/backends-in-rails-3-1

Comment: I just got done looking at the everydayrails.com one. The issues with it is that it's inheriting AccplicationController and thus getting the default application.html file from my app. Ideally it'd be nice to separate all the styling and js code.

Comment: @ninja08 you can make another controller called `AdminController < ApplicationController` and there set `layout 'backend.html.erb`. Then inherit all your backend controllers from admincontroller.

Answer (score 2):

All of those things can be done via Active Admin, but as it was pointed out, it can be quite a nightmare actually implementing certain things depending on the amount of flexibility you need it to have.  For that exact reason, I decided to start rolling my own administration panels.

Comment: OK then I guess I should probably write my own.. Could you perhaps point me in the right direction? How should I start? Is there any material online that could perhaps help me? Thank you..

Comment: use the inherited_resources gem to keep your code dry. and ryan bates has some great tuts on authorization and authentication from scratch http://railscasts.com/?tag_id=25 and http://railscasts.com/?tag_id=26

Comment: Thank you.. I also found this: [backends in rails 3.1](http://iain.nl/backends-in-rails-3-1) in case anyone else wants to create their own backend. I hope its helpful, I'll give it a shot now.